# How to pass options to sequelize afterBulkUpdate

Tags: express, sequelize.js, sequelize-hooks

I'm updating user but then after i need to also update the user_profile table. The user table gets updated but in afterBulkUpdate hook the options is undefined and therefore cannot be destructured and throws an error. How can i pass options while using Model.update and access them in afterBulkUpdate  options. I know i'm passing the options the wrong way, how can i do it right.
This is how i'm doing it

```
User.update({ password : newPassword, phone_number: phoneNumber 
   }, {  where: { username } } , { userOptions: { avatar, nationality, username} } );
```

Then in afterBulkUpdate i want to update the user profile table.

```
  User.afterBulkUpdate(async (user, options) => {
    console.log("user is: ", user); // user is not null
    console.log("options are: ", options); // options is undefined
    const { userOptions} = options;
    const { avatar, nationality, username} = userOptions;

    UserProfile.update({ avatar, nationality} ,{ where: { username }  });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257369/pass-object-into-hook-using-sequelize). I made my own hack to solve the problem, it works, i don't know if its recommended or will have future issues, please advice just in case.

I changed the update to

```
User.update({ password : newPassword, phone_number: phoneNumber 
   }, {  where: { username } , userOptions: { avatar, nationality, username} }  );
```

The userOptions and where clause are passed to the hook as objects in one object, so i changed the afterBulkCreate to

```
User.afterBulkUpdate(async (user, options) => {
    const { userOptions } = user;
    const { avatar, nationality, username} = userOptions;
    UserProfile.update({ avatar, nationality} ,{ where: { username }  });
  });
```