# Passing options to Sequelize hook not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hook

I am currently trying to pass options to a Sequelize hook, but when I try to access the passed options within the hook, they are always undefined.
Anyone got an idea what I am overseeing?

Here's the query:

```
db.customer.findAll({
            where: searchObject,
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            order: orderOptions
        }, {
            user: req.user
        }).then(customers => {
// more code here
```

And here's the model including the hook definition:

```
const db = require("../server/database");
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {

  var Customer = sequelize.define('customer', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    salutation: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    firstName: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    lastName: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  Customer.beforeFindAfterExpandIncludeAll((instance, options) => {
    console.log(options);
  });

  return Customer;
}
```

Comment: What version of sequelize are you using?

Comment: I am using Sequelize v6.3.5

Comment: Can you tell me how the "user" object is defined and where?

Comment: The req.user object is set by passport once a user logs in. The variable is set and shown correctly when logging it to the console.

Comment: @Max I think "user" param being used in findAll function is causing the error. https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll Have a look at the documentation. Please try removing the "user" param and run the query. If you need to use "user" as a param in the query, you might need to modify the model of customer such that it contains "user" as a field and then use the suitable case with user inside where clause.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257369/pass-object-into-hook-using-sequelize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem myself.
I dropped the options part completely and went with the following approach which works just as intended:

```
db.customer.findAll({
            where: searchObject,
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            order: orderOptions,
            user: req.user
        }).then(customers => {
// more code here
```

```
Customer.beforeFindAfterExpandIncludeAll((instance) => {
    console.log(instance.user); // This logs the user object correctly
  });
```

The initial approach was demonstrated in several other StackOverflow posts, but does not appear to be working anymore.

While the approach shown in this post might make it a bit harder to understand the purpose of the user object being passed, it gets the job done just fine.